# Quick way to load images

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, uiimageview, uiimage

Right now I'm loading images view a file url and its taking a long time.  I've even put it on the main thread as a high priority but its still slow.  This is actually in a loop for like 6 images.  My question is:

Is there a faster way to load images to a view than this? Like an alternative to a file url?

```
    //check the filetype
    if ([fileType  isEqual: @"image"])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        //get image
        NSURL *imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:file.url];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            });
        });

    }
```

My images are at a quality of this preset and the size is the size of the iphone screen whether that be a 5,6,or 6 plus

```
self.camera = [[LLSimpleCamera alloc] initWithQuality:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
                                             position:CameraPositionBack
                                         videoEnabled:YES];
```

thanks,

Comment: FYI - If `file.url` is actually returning a file path as a string, then you can't create the `NSURL` using `initWithString`. You need to use `initFileURLWithPath:`. But if `file.url` is returning something like `file://somepath/to/file` then what you have is fine.

Comment: In answer to your question, no, there isn't any shortcut to loading the image.

Comment: This may be of help: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: `videoEnabled:YES` in the `LLSimpleCamera` would indicate you have a video, not a photo. Do you have videos or photos?

Comment: I have both for this app

Comment: 1280x720 images should load from the file system very fast, there is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't any shortcut to loading the images there are things you can do to help.

1. Initially only load the image that are visible, after that load any that may be visible soon.
2. If the size of the image is larger than the view create a smaller image, perhaps a couple for different screen resolution devices.
3. Create a low resolution image versions, load them first to get something up for the user and then load the full resolution images replacing the low resolution version..

Please, Add the sizes of the images and the sizes of the UIImageView and screen resolution to the question.

Comment: I added my quality preset with my possible image sizes

Answer (score 0):

What can I suggest you that,

- Save the duplicate copy of each image in lower resolution/Size on
  server.
- Load the duplicate image on first load.
- When user particularly views an image, load original image then.